# Are armed offenders ready to use their weapons?

Tags: social-psychology, forensic-psychology

Are there any statistics about what proportion of armed attackers are willing to hurt or kill as opposed  only using their weapons as a threat? E.g. There were cases when a self-confident victim without any countermeasure (other than verbal and meta communication) forced the attacker to flee.
Which is more probable? Any studies about the topic?

Comment: Every combat strategist knows that the best win is when you defeat the enemy with your mind.  I suppose the study you seek would be a retrospective; probably quite clouded by how-far in the past the encounter occurred, the low quantity of such data being collected by a trained psychologist, and the infrequent reporting of such encounters

Comment: @NewAlexandria do you have any evidence to support this?